# Prove that if z is a complex number then $\overline{\overline{z}}=z$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So I started off my stating that $z=a+bi$ and $\overline{z}=a-bi$. Then take the conjugate of the conjugate and we get $\overline{\overline{z}}$= $\overline{a-bi}=a+bi$.

Now I'm not sure if this is 100% correct, or that writing a proof like this is correct. If anyone could point me in the right direction please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: If the definition you use for conjugates is that the conjugate of $z=a+bi$ is $\bar z = a-bi$ then that's correct.

Comment: Perhaps you could add that $a$, $b$ are real here.

Comment: If you *really* want, you may introduce an intermediate step: $\overline{\overline{z}}=\overline{a-bi}=\overline{a+(-b)i}=a-(-b)i=a+bi=z$

Comment: You are right, $a+i(-(-b))=a+ib$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometric proof: the conjugation is the symmetry about the horizontal axis. This symmetry is obviously idempotent.